# Apex Code Formatter for SOQL

Tags: vs-code, formatting

I want SOQL fields should be in the same line, not every field goes to a new line,

Current :

[image]

Expected :

`SELECT Field1, Field1, Field1, Field1,....`

`FROM Object`

`WHERE ...`

**.prettierrc**

```
{
"trailingComma": "none",
"singleQuote": true,
"tabWidth": 4,
"overrides": [
    {
        "files": ["force-app/**/**/classes/*.cls"]
    },
    {
        "files": "force-app/**/**/lwc/**/*.html",
        "options": { "parser": "lwc" }
    }
 ]
 }
```

Comment: I like this format too, and I usually just type it out like that.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately prettier code formatter cannot be customized any further and it is as design.

[Prettier Option Philosophy](https://prettier.io/docs/en/option-philosophy.html)

> Prettier is not a kitchen-sink code formatter that attempts to print your code in any way you wish. It is opinionated.

[Why Prettier?](https://prettier.io/docs/en/why-prettier.html)

> By far the biggest reason for adopting Prettier is to stop all the on-going debates over styles. It is generally accepted that having a common style guide is valuable for a project and team but getting there is a very painful and unrewarding process. People get very emotional around particular ways of writing code and nobody likes spending time writing and receiving nits.